# Customer custom attribute not showing in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created custom module for creating custom attribute in **Magento2**. I installed a custom module in local system there is working fine.

My **Local** Magento version is `2.1.6`, I installed this custom module in **Production** environment and it doesn't work.

The **Production** Magento version is `2.2.3`  custom attribute is showing in `eav_attribute` table but, not showing in admin dashboard !

eav attibute table shows custom attribute:

[image]

Comment: did you try `php bin/magento index:reindex` ?

Comment: yes i have run this command

Comment: Did this module is compatible with the both versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

priviously my code is

```
$magentoUuidAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
    ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'uuid');
$magentoUuidAttribute->addData([
    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
 ]);
```

It seem to be visible only when there full 4 opitons of 'used_in_forms' 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer' . Don't worry because even when you set this

```
  $magentoUuidAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'uuid');
 $magentoUuidAttribute->addData([
'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','adminhtml_checkout'],
 ]);
```

Now admin panel showing custom attribute.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. Thanks for your sharing. What do the adminhtml_customer option exactly?